# django form rendering out of order

Tags: django, templates, render, modelform

I'm learning how to use ModelForms and I've successfully gotten the form to render, but the fields aren't showing up in the order that I'd like them to. I tried changing the order in forms.py and that had no effect. How can I go about changing the order; for instance, putting `title` at the top instead of the bottom and making the `picture` field second to last instead of second?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='ad_pictures', default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = {
            'title',
            'body',
            'category',
            'price',
            'picture',
        }
```

views.py

```
def create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return render(request, 'classifieds/latest-ads.html')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'classifieds/create-post.html', args)
```

create.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<!-- {% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'accounts/login.css' %}" type="text/css"> -->
<title>Create Post</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container"><br>
  <form method="POST" action='' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I'd like to point out that in [this](https://youtu.be/Rr1-UTFCuH4?list=LLKPwFmMXR8tQc_mqD4zqrSQ&t=233) video the uploader is able to manipulate the order and have the changed render in the template but I cannot.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [this part of the docs?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.field_order)

Comment: Hadn't seen that so thanks. I'm still not sure where I'd actually put the `Form.order_fields(field_order)` though.

Comment: Was going to show you in an answer, but you posted your `models.py` not `forms.py`... :/ In the video though he's able to change the order, because he's specifying `fields` in the `Meta` of the form. Django will use that order as well

Comment: I have updated the post and I apologize for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `field_order = ['price', 'title', 'body', 'category', 'picture']`

Just replace `{}` with `()` for `fields`

so you should have:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'title',
            'body',
            'category',
            'price',
            'picture',
        )
```